# Exception handling and executing remaining code in document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      1) some code here
      2) some code here
});
```

If for some reason if my code at line1 breaks , all the bindings which are at line2 are not happening. May i know if there is anyway i can complete my bindings like click event , mouseover events etc.

Recently luckly with firebug i found something broke at line1 and that is the reason why my bindings after line1 are not working.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: with this information nobody can answer your question. be more specific. what do you do. what breaks? your code? or does your code trigger something and the exception is thrown inside of jquery core?

Comment: Based on your question, my answer will be.   In that first line of some code something is broken. :)  Fix it and come back. at least post the error or show the code where it breaks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the error throwing code with `try...catch` block